Allow to select multiple buttons
struct Question {
    var title: String
    var options : [String]
}

struct SimpleQuestions: View {
    @State var selectedOption = ""
    @State var question = Question(title: "question title", options: ["one", "two", "three"])
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            Text(question.title)
            ForEach(question.options, id: \.self) { option in
                HStack {
                    Button {
                        selectedOption = option
                    } label: {
                        Circle()
                            .foregroundStyle(selectedOption == option ? .blue : .gray.opacity(0.5))
                            .frame(width: 23, height: 23)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

like this when I click for button it getting disabled for other ones for sure. I couldn't handle multiple selections like user can select as much as they want and button foreground will change. Any suggestion would be great

id: \.self is a mistake, must use valid id

@malhal why is that? do you mean it's not safe to use strings as identifiers?

nope, you can use a string, e.g. id: \.title, you just cant use self

You need a structure that can hold multiple options at once. So you can use for example a Set of options and adapt to it:
struct SimpleQuestions: View {
    @State var selectedOptions: Set<String> = [] //  This accepts multiple options
    @State var question = Question(title: "question title", options: ["one", "two", "three"])
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            Text(question.title)
            ForEach(question.options, id: \.self) { option in
                HStack {
                    Button {
                        if selectedOptions.contains(option) {
                            selectedOptions.remove(option) //  Toggles of if it is on
                        } else {
                            selectedOptions.update(with: option) //  Toggles on if it is off
                        }
                    } label: {
                        Circle()
                            .foregroundStyle(selectedOptions.contains(option) ? .blue : .gray.opacity(0.5)) //  Search in the array and see if it is already selected
                            .frame(width: 23, height: 23)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


Thank a lot, exactly what I m looking.

@kocaman So was it the answer to your needs?
